# submit a form in html

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to submit a form with two components: two dropdown lists. Only the first form 'School' and the submit button itself are submitted. The second form 'pool' is gone somehow.

```
<form method='get'>
    <select name='School'>
        <option>School Name</option>
        <?php while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_object($result)){?>
        <option value= "<?php echo $row->ClientID ?>" > <?php echo $row->ClientName; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>

    <div id='result'>
    <select name='pool1[]' id="pool" multiple="multiple">        
        <option value='de'>de</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="Delete" name="submit2" onclick="removeOption();"/>
    </div>                      

    <div id="teacherdiv">
    <select name="Teacher[]">
        <option>Select Teacher First</option>            
    </select>                    
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Add" name="submit"/>                        

    </form>
```

This is the URL that I got after I pressed the submit button:

**SchoolName.php?School=7&Teacher%5B%5D=Select+Teacher+First&submit=Add**

The pool1 dropdown list is not in there.

Comment: my thoughts are that using get wont work for an array, you would probably need to use post

Comment: Its not named `pool`, it's named `pool1`

Comment: I tested your form its just fine :)

Comment: @Akam Could you show me the generated URL? Thanks!

Comment: `http://127.0.0.1/test.php?pool1[]=de&Teacher[]=Select+Teacher+First&submit=Add` you need to select `de` before submit or make it selected by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the first option selected by default to ensure a value is passed.

Otherwise it will not even pass an empty value.

```
    <select name='pool1[]' id="pool" multiple="multiple">        
        <option value='de' selected="selected">de</option>
    </select>
```